# L Factor of RUSLE methodology

Tags: arcgis-pro, flow-accumulation, rusle

Maybe someone have applied the Desmet and Govers, (1996) methodology for the L factor of the RUSLE model.

How should exactly be performed?

It says that it requires Flow accumulation in square meters. I converted the flow accumulation raster by multiplying it with 625 (25x25m cell size). But the final RUSLE equation returns me soil loss values of up to 700k tonns/year. I have also converted the Aspect, from degrees to radians, as ArcGIS uses radians for raster calculator.

The only data that I can think of causing such a high result is the L factor.

Is the final value of L factor, using the formula by Desmet and Govers, final or should be converted to a different unit?

Comment: I haven't a good answer and this may lead you on a goose chase but.. you could give this a shot and compare outcomes  https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/available_tools/geomorphometric_analysis.html#sedimenttransportindex